# Window scroll event not working in router-outlet angular 4 without doing viewEncapsulation.none

Tags: angular

I have a web app structured with router outlet.I tried to handle an window scroll event in a component,the template of which will be shown inside router outlet.I did this In the following way.

`@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
  onScroll(event){
    console.log(event);
  }`

But it didn't work.But when I changed encapsulation of `app.component.ts` to `ViewEncapsulation.native`then it worked.But changing the encapsulation messed up all other CSS stylings and angular material stuffs.so I am wondering if there is a way around to this without changing the encapsulation.
Thank You

Comment: Where in the code did you use encapsulation? can you create a plunk?

Comment: Are you sure the document is scrolling not an element within the document?

Comment: in  the app.component.ts.I mean in the ts file,the template of  which contains router-outlet

Comment: My Router-outlet is inside a div. Is that doing the problem?@GünterZöchbauer